# TabActivity with ActivityGroup

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

I was able to get a `TabActivity` working properly with multiple `Activity`'s using `ActivityGroup`. However, I noticed a weird behavior. When clicking on multiple screens in one tab, going to another tab and navigating back to the original tab where user was already navigating several screens, the `ActivityGroup` goes back to the main `Activity` rather than the last visited one.

I was following the tutorial here:

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Is there a work around for the `ActivityGroup` to prevent this kind of behavior?

Comment: Why in science's name would you follow a tutorial that uses 2010 material ? Use fragments, this is not 2010 anymore... There's absolutely no excuse for not using fragments.

Comment: Im new to Android dev...but was reading about Fragments. Is it compatible with 2.x versions? I think I would need that backwards compatibility...

Comment: Yes, they are available through the Android Compatibility Package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to look for a tutorial on Fragments.

I know this is not really the answer to your question, but I think it would be better to immediately use Fragments. This because Fragments are now recommended for Android development, and should be used as much as possible in favor of older technologies. And the stuff you want to do, are the perfect example of things that should now be done with Fragments.

The tutorial you are pointing to is from 2010, so that means that the technology used there will be rather old (I haven't read it though, but I can imagine it will). It is best if you want to develop something, to immediately use the latest technology, in this case: Fragments.

Some information on [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)